# onlick event not working within a window.open

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to achieve an onclick event once window.open has opened. So that when the user clicks a button in the new window it works.

The onclick event works if it's not within the newly opened window.

```
<div class="show-dialog" id="content">                                 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var c = document.getElementById("content"); 
      function resizeText(multiplier) { if (c.style.fontSize == "") {c.style.fontSize = "1.0em"; } c.style.fontSize = parseFloat(c.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em"; } 
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="resizeText(1)" id="plustext">Make text bigger</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="resizeText(-1)" id="minustext">Make text smaller</a>

</div>
```

The javascript function enables clicking the links and increasing or decreasing the text. The open.window function opens the new window which is good and is working fine but within my window.open example the onlick event doesn't trigger. So I can't use the function :(

```
<span class="Show"><a href="#">Show<i class="fa fa-external-link-square fa-left"></i></a></span>

$(".Show a").click(function() {
 var e = $(this).parent().next("div.show-dialog").html();
 var t = window.open("", "mywindow1", "width=950,height=550,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes");
t.document.write("<html><head>");
t.document.write("<style>body{font-size:2em;}</style>");
t.document.write("<script type='text/javascript'>

var c = document.getElementById('content');

function resizeText(multiplier) {
  if (c.style.fontSize == '2em')
  { c.style.fontSize = '2em'; } c.style.fontSize = parseFloat(c.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + 'em';
}

</script>");

t.document.write("</head><body>");
$(t.document).find("body").html(e);
t.document.write("<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='resizeText(1)' id='plustext'>Make text bigger</a>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='resizeText(-1)' id='minustext'>Make text smaller</a>");
t.document.write("</body>");
t.document.write("</html");});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Try closing the document after writing to it? t.document.close(); Also, it looks like you might have an undefined variable at line '$(t.document).find('body').html(e)' - I can't see 'e' defined anywhere? Check you console for errors...

Comment: I've added this line to the end of the js and it still doesn't trigger...

Comment: Also, it looks like you might have an undefined variable at line '$(t.document).find('body').html(e)' - I can't see 'e' defined anywhere? Check you console for errors...

Comment: Console is showing this error onclick - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null, how do I fix this ?

Comment: I can't see an element with an id="content" anywhere. Therefore, 'c' is null. Also, at that point 'c' will always be null as there is no elemnt before it that will have an id="content". Create an element with id="content" within the body element and move the 'var c = document.getElementById('content');' line to within the resizeText function.

Comment: Brilliant, I've done that and no console errors are appearing but now the buttons aren't showing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87847/discussion-between-adam-kolinski-and-steven-anderson).

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87847/discussion-between-adam-kolinski-and-steven-anderson

Answer (score 2):

In the end I managed to get the onclick even to work within the window.open.

I also was intergrating a function to increase and decrease the font-size within the window.open onclick.

```
// Creating window to open for text that are in div with class name show-dialog
$(".Show a").click(function() {
    // Varible grabs content of show dialogs
    var activityContent =  $(this).parent().next("div.show-dialog").html();
    // Establish varibale to create buttons to increase text
    var userGUI = "<div class='userGUI'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='resizeText(1)' id='plustext'><i class='fa fa-plus-square-o fa-2x'></i></a>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='resizeText(-1)' id='minustext'><i class='fa fa-minus-square-o fa-2x'></i></a><br>Increase / Decrease font size.</div>";
    // Created variable for the window.open
    var inWindow = window.open("", "mywindow1", "width=950,height=550,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes");

    // Writing to the inWindow variable
    inWindow.document.write("<html><head>");
    inWindow.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'><link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
    inWindow.document.write("<title>Hello world</title>");
    inWindow.document.write("<style>body{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.8;}a{color:#663366;}a:hover{color:#844484;}.userGUI{float:right;}</style>");
    inWindow.document.write("</head><body id='content'>");

    $(inWindow.document).find("body").append(userGUI);
    $(inWindow.document).find("body").append("<br><br>");
    $(inWindow.document).find("body").append(activityContent);

    inWindow.document.write("</body><script type='text/javascript'>
    // Increase font size function
    function resizeText(multiplier) {
      var c = document.getElementById('content');
      if (c.style.fontSize == '')
      { c.style.fontSize = '1.175em'; } c.style.fontSize = parseFloat(c.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + 'em';
    }</script></html>");
    inWindow.document.write("");
    inWindow.document.close();
});
```

The html to this is in my question above ^.