# Onlick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I'm newbie in programming. I would like to open a link by using `onclick` event but this doesn't work....Can you help me please?

Here the code:

```
$content .= '<a class="mike-link mike-pinterest" 
                href="'.$pinterestURL.'" data-pin-custom="true" target="_blank" 
                onclick="window.open("", "mikewindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
                return false;">Pin It</a>' ;
```

Comment: This does not really look like Java to me. Are you sure you are talking about Java?

Comment: this seems like javascript or similar, not java

Comment: It's PHP folks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onlick event not working within a window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194746/onlick-event-not-working-within-a-window-open)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$content .= '<a class="mike-link mike-pinterest" 
            href="' . $pinterestURL . '" data-pin-custom="true" target="_blank" 
            onclick="window.open(\'\', \'mikewindow\',\'menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250\');
            return false;">Pin It</a>';
```

Your problem was that you used double quotes to open the onclick, but then double quotes again inside the window.open function, which instead closed the onclick action quotes. The tricky thing is that using single quotes will close your php quotes. So what you do is use `\'`, which lets php ignore the single quote, and write it as a single quote in your html.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is the following:

```
$content .= '<a class="mike-link mike-pinterest" 
            href="javascript:window.open("'.$pinterestURL.'", "mikewindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
            return false;" data-pin-custom="true" target="_blank" 
            >Pin It</a>' ;
```

Comment: No. That attempts to use the value of `$pinterestURL` as a JavaScript identifier when it should be a string.

Comment: You've failed to account for the other `"` characters too.

Comment: I messed up with parenthesis, but should get the idea

Comment: You messed up a lot more than the parenthesis. In fact, the parenthesis are about the only thing you didn't mess up.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> onclick="window.open("", "mikewindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
> ```

Your first `"` starts the attribute value.

Then you say `window.open(` which is the attribute value.

Then you say `"` which marks the end of the attribute value.

Then you say `"` again, which is invalid HTML.

---

If you want to include a `"` as data in an HTML attribute delimited with `"` characters then you need to encode it as `&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

Check this this codepen link:

```
<p>Click Me!</p>  

 $('p').click(function(){
   window.open('https://google.com');
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjRbEW